# C++ Pipe Skills that makes the ReadFile and WriteFile functions available at the same time

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, named-pipes

Pipe is being used, If server call `WriteFile`/`ReadFile`, client have to call `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` **for synchronize each other**.I implemented it like this.

Example :

**COMMON : **

```
BOOL RecvData(DWORD &dwScore)
{
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    if(0 == ReadFile(g_hPipe, &dwScore, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, 0))
        return FALSE;
    if (sizeof(DWORD) != dwRead)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL SendData(DWORD dwScore)
{
    DWORD dwSend = 0;
    if(0 == WriteFile(g_hPipe, &dwScore, sizeof(DWORD), &dwSend, 0))
        return FALSE;
    if (sizeof(DWORD) != dwSend)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

**SERVER : **

```
VOID StartServerManager()
{
    DWORD dwScore = 0;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if(FALSE == RecvData(dwScore))
            continue;
        //.... do something dwScore + dwSkill ... 
        if(FALSE == SendData(dwScore))
            continue;

    }
}
```

**CLIENT : **

```
#define VILLA_READ_MODE 0xDEDC
#define VILLA_WRITE_MODE 0xCDEC

VOID StartClientManager()
{
    DWORD dwScore = 4;
    DWORD dwMode = VILLA_WRITE_MODE;
    while(TRUE)
    {
        switch(dwMode)
        {
        case VILLA_WRITE_MODE:
            SendData(dwScore);
            dwMode = VILLA_READ_MODE;
            break;
        case VILLA_READ_MODE:
            RecvData(dwScore);
            dwMode = VILLA_WRITE_MODE;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**If I change `StartServerManager()` into like this**

```
VOID StartServerManager()
{
    DWORD dwScore = 0;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if(FALSE == RecvData(dwScore))
            continue;
        //.... do something dwScore + dwSkill ... 

        if(FALSE == SendData(dwScore))
            continue;

        if(FALSE == RecvData(dwScore))
            continue;

        if(FALSE == RecvData(dwScore))
            continue;

    }
}
```

**Function will block at `ReadFile()`**

**`if(0 == ReadFile(g_hPipe, &dwScore, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, 0))`**

```
BOOL RecvData(DWORD &dwScore)
{
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    if(0 == ReadFile(g_hPipe, &dwScore, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, 0))
        return FALSE;
    if (sizeof(DWORD) != dwRead)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Implemented with threads, too.
Is there any method pass block on ReadFile?
I thought about this...

```
#define VILLA_READ_MODE 0xDEDC
#define VILLA_WRITE_MODE 0xCDEC
VOID StartClientManager()
{
    HANDLE hThread[2];
    DWORD dwModeRead = VILLA_READ_MODE;
    DWORD dwModeWrite = VILLA_WRITE_MODE;
    hThread[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SYNCTHREAD, &dwModeRead, 0, 0);
    hThread[2] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SYNCTHREAD, &dwModeWrite, 0, 0);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);
}
DWORD WINAPI SYNCTHREAD(DWORD &dwMode)
{
    switch (dwMode)
    {
    case VILLA_READ_MODE:
        RecvData(dwScore);
        break;
    case VILLA_WRITE_MODE:
        SendData(dwScore);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: in `SendData` need `WriteFile` use instead `ReadFile` or this is typo ?

Comment: thank you. RbMm. It was my mistake.

Comment: The client always alternates between reading and writing, so it makes no sense for the server to try to read two values in a row.  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: If server send data(WriteFile) to client, client function ReadFile will pass.

Comment: If server send data(WriteFile) to client, 1. client function ReadFile will pass > then analysis the received data > 2. WriteFile() -> Data > 3. Wait for server data at ReadFile() again. But in step 3., if server doesn't send data, only want to ReadFile, it's blocked at Client&Server ReadFile. So I Want to know a method of how set ReadFile, WriteFile function time out. Even if I solve it, 30% is solved. Thankyou Harry Johnston. Have a good day.

Comment: Well ... you can abort a synchronous ReadFile using threads and the CancelSynchronousIo function, or you could use asynchronous I/O instead.  But note that timeouts are unlikely to resolve your problem.  Also, the code in the latest edit does not appear to make any sense.  I suspect that you are confused about what you are trying to achieve, and adding timeouts is only going to make things worse.  (If your goal is to share a variable between two processes, consider using shared memory and a named mutex instead of a pipe.)